# How to pass a class type as parameter and cast to it?

Tags: java

Why can't I cast an object to a class type that I provide via paramter?

```
public static checkInstanceOf(Object obj, Class<?> type) {
    return obj instanceof type; //error: type cannot be resolved to a type
}
```

I'd like to create a utility method that has to use an instanceof check like this in a more detailed routine. What would I have to change?

I'd like to be able to call something like this:

```
MyUtil.checkInstanceOf(new String(""), MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [`isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method of the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class.

Comment: Great. Another question: can I also cast my object to that instance soemhow?

Comment: Help yourself to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: Casting is a compile-time thing.  Do you mean "convert"?

Comment: *checked* casting is a runtime operation and it can be done reflectively.

Comment: @Maroun - was there a reason why you removed the link to the Javadoc?  I was about to put it back, but Marko has beaten me to it.

Comment: @david he just hyperlinked the method name.

Comment: @DavidWallace I made it clickable on `isInstance`. I just wanted to improve your answer.

Comment: Hehe, no, @Maroun, that's cool.  I didn't see that the method name was now a link.  It looked to me like you had just removed the link and I couldn't understand why.

Comment: @DavidWallace That's OK :) You'll get used to it :D

Comment: @membersound - what do you hope to achieve with your casting?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: OK I see casting by runtime is not the best to look for. So will have to cast outside of this method.

Comment: This article may help you - http://astroboid.com/2010/06/simple-java-tip-checked-type-casting.html